How can I install libraries and headers on MinGW so they will be automatically found by the compiler?
Basically, I have this C project that I decided to distribute as a static library.
The library builds and gets installed (along with a header file) by a CMake file (code below).
The problem is that, while the CMake file works perfectly on Linux, on Windows it just installs the files in /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/include (aka C:\msys64\usr\local\lib and C:\msys64\usr\local\include) and AFAIK those places are not looked in by GCC. In fact, inside of those two folders there are just the files put there by CMake (libprimes.a in the first directory and primes.h in the latter), and nothing else. If I try to #include <primes.h> inside of a C file, it simply says that the header file could not be found.
My question is, how could I edit the CMakeLists.txt file in order to make it work both on Windows  and Linux OOB? (if that's even possible?)
CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(libprimes VERSION 1.0.1)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O2 -g -DNDEBUG -Os")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g -O0 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -pedantic")

option(BUILD_TESTS "Build tests" ON)

add_library(primes STATIC src/primes.c src/sieve.c)
target_include_directories(primes PUBLIC "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
target_link_libraries(primes PRIVATE pthread m)

install(TARGETS primes DESTINATION lib)
install(FILES include/primes.h DESTINATION include)

if(BUILD_TESTS)
    enable_testing()
    add_subdirectory(tests)
endif()

target_compile_options(primes PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra)

I think that the problem is CMake defaulting to those two directories, while the actual ones should be C:\msys64\mingw64\usr\lib and C:\msys64\mingw64\usr\include, but I'm afraid that it can also be environment-dependent.
Is there a standard way to install C static libraries on Windows (via CMake) that I'm missing?

I haven't done dev work on Windows in close to two decades, but I don't think there are any standard directories to search.  Why not just use CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX at configuration time?  If you're distributing pre-built binaries, the archive you distribute can be extracted wherever a user needs it for their system.

Please [edit] your question and explain what exactly means "there are just the files put there by CMake, and nothing else". What files are there. Are you using the same compiler, cmake and MSys environment when you try to build your application?

@Bodo Hi. I don't think I fully get what you mean. I'm using GCC 13 and CMake 3.10>. Anyways I've updated the question body.

I thought about the difference between C:\msys64\... and C:\msys64\mingw64\.... Do you use find_library and find_path in your application's CMakeLists.txt? Show this file in your question. Or do you otherwise specify compiler and linker flags like -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib?

@Bodo The CMake code is already in the question. I still don't get it.

The question shows the CMakeLists.txt for building your library but not the file for an application that uses the library.

Well, you simply include the header and then link with "-lprimes" at compile time. No CMake required.

Here's the trick I use which works independently of the build tools being used (autoconf, CMake, Meson, ...):
Solution
Set the CPATH environment variable to the path containing C and C++ headers.
Set the LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to the path containing the library files (.a files).
Setting the environment
Warning
I strongly advise to never set system-wide environment variables. Instead start your shell with a script to set these variables.
MSYS2 solution
When using MSYS2 shell you could the following lines to .bash_profile or .profile (replace /c/prog/mingw as needed):
export CPATH=/c/prog/mingw/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=/c/prog/mingw/lib

Alternative MSYS2 solution
Alternatively create a dedicated script and pass that to MSYS2's bash.exe via the --rcfile parameter when starting your shell.
This could look like this:
CD C:\Prog\Environment1
C:\Prog\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe --noprofile --rcfile profile_settings.sh -i

Where C:\Prog\Environment1 contains a file profile_settings.sh with the above export commands.
This has the additional advantage that you can create multiple separate environments, each with different (versions of) libraries installed.

Do I have to adjust the CMake file so that it will use the CPATH and LIBRARY_PATH env-vars as the destination for the files? If yes, will it need to "expect" these two variables to be already set when installing on another user's system?

No, just the shell from where you run cmake. In fact you should try to keep CMakeLists.txt as universal as possible and then run cmake with specifics flags for the build you want to do, like -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Windows -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE=ONLY -DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY=ONLY or even more specifics like  -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-I/c/Prog/mingw64/include"
